# magento2 move product image after product title

Tags: magento2

How can I move the Product image after product title?

In short, I can say I need to move **product media** div inside **class="product-info-main"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried you questions.may be help this

Open this file `catalog_product_view.xml`

And put this code : -

```
<move element="product.info.media" destination="page.main.title" after="-"/>
```

You put this after run `php bin/magento c:c`

And last your `product media` div move on product-info-main div

[image]

Hope this helps you

Thanks ...